# Why in Dummit & Foote all modules are unital?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

I do not understand the pathology that will result from taking non unital modules in Dummit & Foote in the following paragraph:

[image]

Could anyone explain it in detail for me please?

thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They don't find it interesting to have modules $M\neq\{0\}$ such that$$(\forall r\in R)(\forall m\in M):r.m=0$$(and neither do I). If we impose that $(\forall m\in M):1.m=m$ (a natural hypothesis), that cannot occur.

Comment: Well, they do allow one case of those modules, namely the zero module. But they want no others (which is a very natural choice).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Quite right. I shall edit my answer.

Answer (score 7):

Another way to see why such a requirement can be considered natural is that the authors presumably already require that homomorphisms of rings send $1$ to $1$ (again, that this is a natural requirement is good to think about).

An equivalent definition of a $R$-module is the following:

An $R$-module $M$ is an abelian group $M$ together with a ring homomorphism from $R$ to the ring of endomorphisms of $M$.
The requirement that the module is unital is then precisely the requirement that this homomorphism sends $1$ to $1$, as we already required our homomorphisms of rings to do.

Comment: *For OP:* In Dummit and Foote, a ring doesn't necessarily contain identity (so of course $1 \mapsto 1$ doesn't make sense). That's why, in the definition of left-module, authors insisted *"if the ring $R$ has a $1$ **we impose** the additional axiom: $1\cdot m =m, \,\, \forall m \in M$"* (this is axiom 2(d)). This is a natural condition to assume, as pointed out in this answer.